# I need help in drawing a grid on a WPF DrawingContext that conforms to pixel boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to draw a grid on physical device pixel boundaries but it isn't working.  To take the enclosed example code, the first line is one pixel to the left, the second, one to the right, etc.  I want to generate a pixel-perfect grid on devices that don't have 96 pixels to the inch.  Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated....

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    var  m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice;

    double dpiFactor = 1 / m.M11;

    var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1 * dpiFactor);

    double halfPenWidth = pen.Thickness / 2.0;

    for (int x = 1; x <= Consts.GridSize - 1; x++)
    {
        var p1 = new Point(Consts.CellSize * x, 0);
        var p2 = new Point(Consts.CellSize * x, Height - 1);

        var rect = new Rect(p1, p2);

        var guidelines = new GuidelineSet();

        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Left + halfPenWidth);
        guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Right + halfPenWidth);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Top + halfPenWidth);
        guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Bottom + halfPenWidth);

        drawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, pen, rect);
        //drawingContext.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);
        drawingContext.Pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF is resolution independent. The 96 pixels per inch is just used for `Image` resolution and not the output resolution.

Comment: @Sheridan How WPF maps its "device indepedent units" to screen pixels depends on Window's screen resolution setting. With the default value of 96 dpi (or 100%) a WPF pixels exactly matches a screen pixel. If the system setting differs (e.g. 120 dpi, or 125%) there is no exact match anymore.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get my lines spaced evenly.  This is a very visible problem on my laptop